# How to play iptv channel using VLC player instead max player?

Tags: android, vlc, iptv, vlc-android

I have referred https://github.com/AlexanderSofronov/iptv.example for implementing iptv channels which is working fine, but it plays video using max player. But I want to play iptv channel using VLC player in application.

How can I integrate VLC player instead max player?

Comment: You can integrate vlc your self .https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to reset your default app settings. in case if you dont know how to reset it go for the link  below.

[Reset android default apps](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/quick-tip-reset-android-default-apps/)